# Barcode image generating in Zend 1.12 application

Tags: php, zend-framework

I am working on Barcode image generation in Zend 1.12 application.

I am following tutorial [Example #5 Renderering a barcode with the renderer object](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.barcode.creation.html)

I have written below code in controller

```
function barcodeAction()
{
    $barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK');

    // No required options
    $rendererOptions = array();

    // Draw the barcode in a new image,
    // send the headers and the image
    Zend_Barcode::factory(
        'code39', 'image', $barcodeOptions, $rendererOptions
    )->render();
}
```

While accessing barcode action -- Barcode image is not displaying

Below is the html I get from view source

```
<img style="-webkit-user-select: none" src="http://localhost/zend1.12/public/index/barcode">
```

Let me know what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally figured it out
You need to disable the view -- So writing

```
$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
```

in action solved problem

Also noted that the text passed to barcode need to be UPPER case

```
$barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'ZEND-FRAMEWORK'); // This is valid

$barcodeOptions = array('text' => 'Zend-Framework'); // This is not valid
```

Comment: Thanks anyway -- Added extra details about UPPER case letters. Zend documentation is not so clear and sometimes we need to find hidden code standards :)